# Space between uibarbuttons in navigation bar, Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6.1

I have tried almost all answers here, How to remove the blank space between the two uibarbuttons shown below the code i use is

[image]

```
UIButton *backBTN= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[backBTN addTarget:self action:@selector(backACT:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backBTN setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *backkb = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBTN];

// self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backkb;

UIButton *homeBTN= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[homeBTN addTarget:self action:@selector(homeACT:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[homeBTN setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *btnhome = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:homeBTN];
//  btnhome.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10, 0, 0, 0);
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: backkb, btnhome, nil]];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: Can u show image, How it looks with ur code? So we can understand more.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2-shlLtKd9SZzNIVmJvRGxncGs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
    // Create a UIView to add both buttons
    UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];

    UIButton *backBTN= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [backBTN addTarget:self action:@selector(backACT:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [backBTN setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Add button to UIView
    [leftView addSubview:backBTN];

    UIButton *homeBTN= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 30, 30)];
    [homeBTN addTarget:self action:@selector(homeACT:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [homeBTN setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Add button to UIView
    [leftView addSubview:homeBTN];

    //Set UIView as CustomView for bar button
    UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftView];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: leftBarButton, nil]];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

I have tried this and got output as [image]
used some background colour to know the borders